# Match pattern with whitespace in lua filter

Tags: lua, pandoc

I have found a lua filter for pandoc which transforms patterns like `[[Link]]` to `file:///Link`. Right now it doesn't match patterns like `[[Link more words]]` though.

1. I would like to also match patterns like `[[Link more words]]` and
2. transform spaces into `%20`.

So that the result would look like `file:///Link%20more%20words`.

```
local List = require 'pandoc.List'

return {
  {
    Str = function (elem)
      local tgt

      --we have to return a list of Inline objects
      local rlst = {}

      -- match a [[...]] string element
      tgt = elem.text:match("%[%[(.+)%]%]")
      if tgt == null then
        return null  -- no match, null means leave element unchanged
      else
        -- successful match, construct a Link element to go back in the AST 

        -- I suppose we should make a local file url as the target
        local urlText = "file:///" .. tgt .. ""  
        -- the link text should look like it did in obsidian 
        local linkText = "[[" .. tgt .. "]]"

        -- single element return list
        rlst[1] = pandoc.Link( List:new( {pandoc.Str(linkText)} ), urlText )
        return rlst     
      end
    end,
  }
}
```

([Source of the filter on the Obsidian Discord by spacejunky](https://discord.com/channels/686053708261228577/694233507500916796/713283082068820049))

Answer (score 0):

Just replace whitespace with "%20" using [string.gsub](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub).

```
local txt = "Hello world!"

txt = txt:gsub("%s+", "%%20")

print(txt)
```

> Hello%20world!

Comment: Thanks, that solves the second part of the question. I made the question more clear now. Because my first problem is that it doesn't match something like `[[Link more words]]`.

Comment: but `"%[%[(.+)%]%]"` will match `"[[Link more words]]"` I don't see your problem. This pattern captures any +1 characters in [[ ]]

Comment: Mh, for me it doesn't work in pandoc though:

`echo "blah [[Link]] blah" | pandoc --lua-filter=links.lua` results in `<p>blah <a href="file:///Link">[[Link]]</a> blah</p>`

But `echo "blah [[Link more words]] blah" | pandoc --lua-filter=links.lua` results in `<p>blah [[Link more words]] blah</p>`

Comment: then I don't know. Lua-wise that's what you need. `.` will match all characters. So no matter what is inbetween those brackets will be matched. the only way I can think of to make this fail is to mess up the braces somehow.

Comment: Ok, then it must be pandoc-related. I will try to figure it out somehow.

Comment: The issue is that pandoc splits the links across multiple words. The text `[[Multiple words]]` would be represented as the list of elements `{Str '[[Multiple', Space, Str 'words]]'}`. So one would have to step through lists of inline elements (with a filter on `Inlines`) to parse these links.